# Linear First-Order ODE - Why Must Integrating Factor Always be f(x)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm going through Riley's Math Methods and, in going over the simple case of a linear first-order ODE, he mentions how it is a specific case of the first-order, first-degree inexact equations discussed in the previous section. Obviously, this follows directly from a simple rearrangement of the conventional form for the linear ODE to make it into the total differential form (sans integrating factor) used to analyze inexact equations. He then goes on to state that, in this case, the integrating factor $\mu$ will always be $f(x)$ (rather than, say, $g(y)$ or $h(x,y)$). I tried to work through why that *must* be true in the general case. Below is my thinking, but I can't seem to go any further to prove it.
We begin in the standard form for such ODEs

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
$$dy+(P(x)y-Q(x))dx=0=Ady+Bdx$$
for some A and B.
Thus, using the equality of mixed partial derivatives, we require $\mu$ such that
$$\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}B+\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}\mu$$

but $\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}$ is $P(x)$ so we arrive at 
$$\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}B+P(x)\mu$$

From here I cannot see how to make any more simplifications and place any more restrictions on $\mu$ so as to demonstrate that it must be $f(x)$. Any direction in this respect would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because it works with $\mu=\exp(\int P(x)dx)$. If $Mdx+Ndy=0$ has an integrating factor $\mu$ so that the expression integrates to $F(x,y)=C$, then also any function 
$\tilde\mu=G(F(x))\mu$ will be an integrating factor, however in most cases such modifications will give a more complicated expression.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. I get that I could show the above "by cases" (ie. by showing that there is some contradiction when the assumption of $\mu=\mu(y)$ or $\mu=\mu(x,y)$ is made), but I'm wondering if there is a direct way to do it as is asked above.

Comment: There does not exist a general recipe to find integrating factors. There are classes of cases that are more or less practically relevant where a simplifying assumption leads to a solution, but while they are over-represented in text-book exercises, in any general framework they form only a very thin set.

Comment: Yup, I absolutely follow that. But what I'm asking for is a general proof that in a *linear* first-order ODE we will ALWAYS have an integrating factor that is only $\mu(x)$, rather than the more general case of a first-order first-degree ODE where we may well have the more difficult case of $\mu(x,y)$.

Comment: It just works. Just insert it to confirm it. There is no deeper reason.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you!